# What does a Ruby case expression mean without an expression to inspect?

Tags: ruby, syntax, switch-statement, semantics

Take this example Ruby expression:

```
case
  when 3 then "foo"
  when 4 then "bar"
end
```

I was surprised to learn that this is not a syntax error. Instead, it evaluates to `"foo"`!

Why? What are the syntax and evaluation rules being applied here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this form of the `case` expression, the `then` clause associated with the lexically first `when` clause that evaluates to a *truthy* value is evaluated.

See clause b) 2) of §11.5.2.2.4 *Semantics* of the [ISO Ruby Language Specification](http://iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59579) (**bold** emphasis mine):

> ## Semantics
>
> A case-expression is evaluated as follows:
>
> - a) […]
> - b. The meaning of the phrase “O is matching” in Step c) is defined as follows:
>
>   1. […]
>   2. **If the *case-expression* is a *case-expression-without-expression*, *O* is matching if and only if *O* is a trueish object.**
> - c) Take the following steps:
>
>   1. Search the *when-clause*s **in the order they appear in the program text** for a matching *when-clause* as follows:
>
>      - i) If the *operator-expression-list* of the *when-argument* is present:
>      - I) For each of its *operator-expression*s, evaluate it and test if the resulting value is matching.
>      - II) If a matching value is found, other *operator-expression*s, if any, are not evaluated.
>      - ii) If no matching value is found, and the *splatting-argument* (see 11.3.2) is present:
>      - I) Construct a list of values from it as described in 11.3.2. For each element of the resulting list, in the same order in the list, test if it is matching.
>      - II) If a matching value is found, other values, if any, are not evaluated.
>      - iii) A *when-clause* is considered to be matching if and only if a matching value is found in its *when-argument*. Later *when-clauses*, if any, are not tested in this case.
>   2. If one of the *when-clause*s is matching, evaluate the *compound-statement* of the *then-clause* of this *when-clause*. The value of the *case-expression* is the resulting value.
>   3. If none of the *when-clause*s is matching, and if there is an *else-clause*, then evaluate the *compound-statement* of the *else-clause*. The value of the *case-expression* is the resulting value.
>   4. Otherwise, the value of the *case-expression* is `nil`.

The [RDoc documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000011), while much less precise, also states that *truthiness* is the selection criteria, when the condition is omitted; and lexical ordering determines the order in which `when` clauses are checked (**bold** emphasis mine):

> ## `case`
>
> The case statement operator. Case statements consist of an **optional condition**, which is in the position of an argument to `case`, and zero or more `when` clauses. **The first `when` clause** to match the condition (or to **evaluate to Boolean truth, if the condition is null**) "wins", and its code stanza is executed. The value of the case statement is the value of the successful `when` clause, or `nil` if there is no such clause.

Comment: Your code examples are not equivalent. In your example, `3` would not match since `3 === true` is `false`. The answer by Andrey is actually correct.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea what I was thinking! Is that better?

Comment: BTW: I just noticed that the "equivalent" code samples in the docs are also wrong. Meh.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. This is much better now. Also thanks for quoting from the ISO standard since it's quite an expensive reference :)

Comment: Don't tell anyone I'm quoting from the Draft, then! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It is by design that `case` statement without a value to match against behaves as an `if` statement.

It **is actually** the same as writing:

```
if 3
  'foo'
elsif 4
  'bar'
end
```